# On expressing a square as a sum of two cubes

Tags: diophantine-equations, conjectures

Given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ which satisfy the following conditions:

1. $a^3 + b^3 = c^2$
2. $ a \neq b$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

EDIT, Will Jagy: The conjecture is that, for a given $c,$ there are at most two distinct pairs  $(a,b)$  with $1 \leq a < b$ and $a^3 + b^3 = c^2.$ Note the example  $77976^2=1026^3+1710^3=228^3+1824^3$ that Gerry found with exactly two pairs.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

There are maximum $2$ possible pairs of $(a, b)$ which satisfy this conditions.

I have verified it for $a, b \leq 200\,000$.

Note: the situation when $a$ and $b$ just take each others value is discarded.

Comment: Please see: http://www.alpertron.com.ar/SUMPOWER.HTM#Pn_3_2, also, see line 127 at: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html

Comment: This paper may help (but it is late, so proceed with caution): https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf

Comment: There are plenty of solutions: $(1,2)$, $(2,46)$, $(11,37)$, $(23,1177)$, $(56,65)$, ...

Comment: 1) reminds me of Ramanujan's number. Except it's not a perfect square.

Comment: @lhf, I think the question is whether for a given $c$ there are more than two pairs $a,b$ etc.

Comment: @Amzoti, I don't think those references deal with the question, whether for given $c$ there are more than two pairs $a,b$ etc.

Comment: The example (not counterexample) $77976^2 = 1026^3 + 1710^3 = 228^3 + 1824^3$ is given at problem 004:01 at http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/goddardb/WCNT11/problems2004.pdf

Comment: @anon, I've taken the liberty of editing title and tag.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, _"I don't think those references deal with the question, whether for given c there are more than two pairs a,b etc. "_, you got the point.

Comment: Why would you expect a restricting taxicab numbers to square to also restrict them to have at most 2 representations? This is a highly interesting problem.

Comment: The utexas link in an earlier comment is dead. Use https://wcnt.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/wcnt-problems-2004.pdf instead. The question there is whether there's a square that the sum of cubes of two *primes* in two different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [oeis](http://oeis.org/A050801), the first square that can be expressed as a sum of two cubes in three different ways is $$3343221000^2 = 279300^3 + 2234400^3 = 790020^3 + 2202480^3 = 1256850^3 + 2094750^3.$$ Perhaps the smallest in four ways, $$\eqalign{42794271007595289^2 &= 14385864402^3 + 122279847417^3\cr &= 55172161278^3 + 118485773289^3\cr &= 64117642953^3 + 116169722214^3\cr &= 96704977369^3 + 97504192058^3\cr}$$ Possibly the smallest in five ways: $$\eqalign{47155572445935012696000^2 &= 94405759361550^3 + 1305070263601650^3 \cr&= 374224408544280^3 + 1294899176535720^3 \cr&= 727959282778000^3 + 1224915311765600^3 \cr&= 857010857812200^3 + 1168192425418200^3 \cr&= 1009237516560000^3 + 1061381454915600^3\cr}$$